# observeEvent with quoted handler expression

Tags: r, shiny

The app below contains a checkbox (`default`), a selectInput (`letter`), and two actionButtons (`trigger1` and `trigger2`). In the server function, there are two observers:

1. observer 1 fires when the user clicks `trigger1` AND the checkbox is **unchecked**, i.e. `input$default == F`.
2. observer 2 fires when the user clicks `trigger2` AND the checkbox is **checked**, i.e. `input$default == T`.

Here is the app:

```
library("shiny")

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxInput('default','Default'),
  selectInput('letter', 'Letter', letters),
  actionButton('trigger1', 'Trigger 1'),
  actionButton('trigger2', 'Trigger 2')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  letter = reactive(input$letter)

  #Observer 1
  observeEvent(input$trigger1, {
    req(!input$default)
    print(letter())
  })

  #Observer 2
  observeEvent(input$trigger2, {
    req(input$default)
    print(letter())
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Both observers share the same handler expression, i.e. `print(letter())` and I was wondering if there was an alternative to having to write it out separately for each observer? This would be useful because the handler expression in my actual app is several lines long.

One way to do this would be to have a `reactiveVal` that changes in response to `input$trigger1` or `input$trigger2`, depending on the value of `input$default`:

```js
server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
  letter = reactive(input$letter)
  
  t = reactiveVal(0)
  
  observeEvent(input$trigger1, {
    req(!input$default) 
    t(t()+1)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$trigger2, {
    req(input$default) 
    t(t()+1)
  })
  
  observeEvent(t(), print(letter()), ignoreInit = T)
  
}
```

But I was wondering if it would be possible to store the expression in a variable and then evaluate it inside the observer using something like `eval`? Here is my attempt:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  letter = reactive(input$letter)

  handler = quote(print(letter()))

  #Observer 1
  observeEvent(eventExpr = {if(isolate(input$default)) return(); input$trigger1}, 
               handlerExpr = eval(handler))

  #Observer 2 - not working
  observeEvent(eventExpr = {if(!isolate(input$default)) return(); input$trigger2}, 
               handlerExpr = eval(handler))

}
```

**EDIT:** This seems to work fine for observer 1 but not for observer 2 due to the `isolate`.

I'm also wary of using non-standard evaluation as I don't have much experience with it. What's wrong with my use of `eval` above and what is it doing exactly? Is there a better/safer alternative? Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making `letter` your reactive, can you make `print` your reactive?  That way you can avoid having `observeEvent`s for `input$trigger1` and `input$trigger2`.  Thus:

```
print <- reactive({
  req(input$trigger1, input$trigger2, input$letter)
  <your code here>
})
```